# how to change mat button color using css on hover?

Tags: css

I want to change color on hover for mat button using css

```
mat-raised-button color="primary">button</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

(for instance, primary color is red)
(hover color is  blue)

CSS:

```
.mat-rised-button{
    color: red;
}
.mat-rised-button:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

(!!! Color tag in CSS changes only font color, if you need whole background color of element, you should use: `background: "color";`)
HTML:

```
<button class="mat-rised-button">Button</button>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9davwnbp/)